# SKSpriteNodes "oscillating" when moving (Sprite Kit)

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I am making a simple game with a car that drives on a terrain, similar to hill climb racing. The car will be made with 3 SKShapeNodes: 1 for the body and 2 for the wheels, and will use SKPhysicsJointPins to attach the wheels to the body. I got the car setup and the ground created, however, whenever the car moves, it seems to "oscillate" in place, which looks very weird to someone playing the game.

Here is a gif of the car "oscillating" in place (only "oscillates" when moving): `https://imgur.com/a/3A5wgXf`

Initially, I thought it was a problem with the car, so I decided to get rid of it and make an independent circle SKShapeNode and move it by applying an impulse, however even it oscillates.

Heres my code: (Im using SwiftUI, so the GameScene will be in a SpriteView)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    
    let roverBody: SKShapeNode = {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: -150, y: -50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: -50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -100, y: 50))
        path.closeSubpath()
        
        let node = SKShapeNode(path: path)
        node.fillColor = SKColor.blue
        node.strokeColor = .black
        node.lineWidth = 5
        
        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
        node.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        node.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    
        
        return node
    }()
    
    let wheel1: SKShapeNode = {
        let path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: -50, y: -50, width: 100, height: 100), transform: nil)
        
        let node = SKShapeNode(path: path)
        node.fillColor = SKColor.gray
        node.strokeColor = .black
        node.lineWidth = 5
        
        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
        node.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
      
        
        return node
    }()
    
    let wheel2: SKShapeNode = {
        let path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: -50, y: -50, width: 100, height: 100), transform: nil)
        
        let node = SKShapeNode(path: path)
        node.fillColor = SKColor.gray
        node.strokeColor = .black
        node.lineWidth = 5
        
        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
        node.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    

        return node
    }()
    
    let ground: SKShapeNode = {
        var splinePoints = [
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200),
            CGPoint(x: 2000, y: 200),
            CGPoint(x: 2600, y: 600),
            CGPoint(x: 2700, y: 200),
            CGPoint(x: 2701, y: -600),
            CGPoint(x: 2900, y: -599),
            CGPoint(x: 3100, y: 600),
            CGPoint(x: 4000, y: 600),
            CGPoint(x: 4000, y: -1000),
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1000),
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200)
        ]

        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &splinePoints, count: splinePoints.count)
        shapeNode.lineWidth = 5
        shapeNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: shapeNode.path!)
        shapeNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        shapeNode.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        shapeNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        
      
        
        return shapeNode
    }()
    
  
    var cameraNode: SKCameraNode!
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        roverBody.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY + 150)
        wheel1.position = CGPoint(x: roverBody.frame.minX + 20, y: roverBody.frame.minY)
        wheel2.position = CGPoint(x: roverBody.frame.maxX - 20, y: roverBody.frame.minY)
        
       
        let wheel1Joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: roverBody.physicsBody!,  bodyB: wheel1.physicsBody!, anchor: wheel1.position)
        
        let wheel2Joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: roverBody.physicsBody!, bodyB: wheel2.physicsBody!, anchor: wheel2.position)
        
     
       
        addChild(roverBody)
        addChild(wheel1)
        addChild(wheel2)
        addChild(ground)
        
        
        self.physicsWorld.add(wheel1Joint)
        self.physicsWorld.add(wheel2Joint)
        
        cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
        self.camera = cameraNode
        addChild(cameraNode)
        
        
    }
    
    var lastPosition: CGPoint?
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
        let torqueMagnitude: CGFloat = 1
        let direction: CGFloat = -1.0
        wheel1.physicsBody?.applyTorque(direction * torqueMagnitude)
        wheel2.physicsBody?.applyTorque(direction * torqueMagnitude)
        
       
        cameraNode.position = roverBody.position
        
    }
}
```

And heres my code to display it in SwiftUI:

```
var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 600,  height: 400)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        return scene
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!